# Is my PSU dying?

Tags: power-supply

I had a GTX 580 3GB, and about 4 weeks ago my PC frequently refused to POST, and sometimes when it was working, the screen would go black and the GPU fan increased to 100%. I would then have to reboot my PC, but the screen would go black progressively more and more quickly.

I read lots of messages on the Nvidia support forum about the latest drivers causing problems, and so yesterday I changed my GPU to the 7970 GHZ Vapor. Now, the PC is beeping 1 long 2 short, and according to the Gigabyte site (my motherboard is the GA-X58A-UD3R rev.2), those beeps correspond to either a monitor problem or GPU. The motherboard speaker (the one that beeps at POST), clicks (that's the best way to describe it) 3 times, and then I get the 1 long and 2 short.

Last night, I got it to work by using different cables on my PSU (Corsair TX 1050), but this morning, it won't POST again and I'm getting the 1 long 2 short.

The only real differences between running with the GTX 580 and the 7970 seem to be that:

1. With the GTX 580, apart from when it POSTed, there were never any other beeps.
2. The PC (in the last 4 weeks), never stayed on as long, without a black screen causing me to reboot.

**Specs:**
Radeon HD 7970 GHZ Vapor Edition
24GB Corsair Dominator
Intel 980x
Corsair TX 1050 (I think it's the TX)
Crucial 256GB SSD (and about 4 Samsung F1's)

I bought all the bits (apart from the 7970) in 2010.

**OCCT Voltages:**
http://i40.tinypic.com/27xfdop.jpg
http://i39.tinypic.com/165kxj.jpg
http://i41.tinypic.com/2mmcpcz.jpg

Right, I've possibly found what's causing the black screen. When I touch the gpu, next to the right pci-e socket, that's when the screen goes blank. Tried it a few times and it's happened on all occasions. The card is seated properly and properly secured. By touch, I mean pressing it up or down gently, maybe about a quarter of an inch (or a bit more).

Comment: Are you sure the new graphics card works properly? I'd try it in a different PC that you know is working properly and that you know has [a powerful enough PSU](http://superuser.com/a/649034/53590), to rule out the possibility of the graphics card simply being bad. Since you say the beep code corresponds to a monitor or GPU problem, I'd say odds are that there is a problem either with the graphics card or how it is installed. If it works in another PC and is seated properly in yours but the computer still gives the same error indication, I'm not sure *off hand* what the problem might be.

Comment: Assuming the voltage graphs are accurate, the +3.3V seems to be a little on the low side, but not out of spec ([+/- 5% is tolerated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply), meaning approximately +3.14V is the minimum valid voltage on the +3.3V rail); the others seem fine.

Comment: Sounds like you should start with the cheapest part and replace the power supply

Comment: I was just about to write this comment, when the screen went blank again, and the gpu fan went to 100%, for no discernible reason. I don't have another pc to try the card in. One thing I have noticed, is that the pc POSTS when it's lying on the table. When it's standing, I have the 1 long 2 short beeps. The GTX 580 displayed the same blank screen and 100% fan symptoms, so isn't it likely to be something other than the card (just wondering) ?

Comment: Right, I've possibly found what's causing the black screen. When I touch the gpu, next to the right pci-e socket, that's when the screen goes blank. Tried it a few times and it's happened on all occasions. The card is seated properly and properly secured.

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/wbdunn.jpg

Comment: http://i43.tinypic.com/i4kbvo.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If the card moves 6-8 mm or more (your "about a quarter of an inch or a bit more"), then I would say that **it is not properly seated and secure.**

This would also explain why it's working better (or "less bad") when the computer is on its side than when it is in a normal upright position. In the former case, the gravitational force on the graphics card pulls it down into the slot; in the latter, gravity exerts a force on the actual graphics card and the only things to resist it is the connection to the slot and the securing screw. Since the graphics card is fairly high-end, those forces can be pretty substantial due to the weight of the components on the card.

If what you mean is that the card *flexes* by that amount when you push down on it, I'd say something is still wrong because it really isn't supposed to. The kind of forces that would propagate through the circuit board from such flexing could easily damage solder joints and electrical traces on the circuit board. I'd say perhaps *half* of that, at most, *might* be acceptable flexing, but even then I'd be wary.

In either case, **you're going to have to figure out why the card moves or flexes by that amount and fix that underlying issue,** and you *may* find yourself needing to get a new card; hopefully, you'll be able to get a replacement under warranty.

Comment: Sorry, yes by moving I meant flexing, and it only that part of the card (that I highlighted in the picture).

Comment: Are the two problems coincidental then ?

Comment: A physically broken graphics card could certainly cause a GPU/monitor error beep code. I can't say for certain that this *is* your problem, but it seems likely to be *a* problem.

Comment: and the GTX 580 which displayed the same blank screen and 100% fan speed ?

Comment: Like I said, I can't say for certain that this *is* your problem, but it seems likely to be *a* problem. OS-level graphics card driver issues shouldn't cause BIOS POST beep error codes either. What I have an issue with is how much the card moves when you touch it. I find it kind of hard to tell from your pictures exactly what you are doing, but from my experience with both computer hardware and electronics in general that amount of flexing just doesn't feel right.

Comment: Do you think my psu has a role to play in these problems ?